# puppet/augeas : parse and save a php file

Tags: puppet

I'm deploying a cakephp application using puppet.
I should need to modify some configuration settings, usually php files, eg. the [database configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html) (values of host, user, password)

What is the best way to have this done?
I was thinking to use augeas, I tried

```
augtool print /files/path/to/app/database.php
```

but seems that augeas has not a lense to parse this kind of file

Answer (score 2):

Augeas lenses are tricky to develop correctly especially for free-form files like Php source code.  I think you are better off converting your database.php file into ERB template.   Puppet has very good support for such templates.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added a resource that explains how to use templates!

Answer (score 0):

Augeas does have a lens to parse PHP files, but you need to tell Augeas that this file is a Phpvars kind of file, it cannot guess it:

```
$ augtool -At "Phpvars.lns incl /path/to/app/database.php"
```

If Augeas can read your file (there is no garantee really, seeing as PHP is not really a configuration language, so it's likely that the file contains real PHP code), then you should be able to see the parsed content with:

```
augtool> print /files
```